# Saving file in a different location in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, file

I am unable to save a file to a different folder(outside app) since i have to retrieve the data from it after the application uninstalled.I have to get the data from that file after installing application.The file is getting deleted with the application.please help me solve this issue..

Comment: have you heard of sandboxing before starting ios programming?

Comment: heard but not sure of its functionality.can u please explain ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Not possible**. iOS apps are sandboxed. You cannot write anything outside your app sandbox.

> For security reasons, iOS places each app (including its preferences and data) in a sandbox at install time. A sandbox is a set of fine-grained controls that limit the app’s access to files, preferences, network resources, hardware, and so on. As part of the sandboxing process, the system installs each app in its own sandbox directory, which acts as the home for the app and its data.

Comment: got it now. so i cannot save any file outside the application.thanks for answering Anil.

Comment: Actuall my requirement was to export data from a DB(sqlite) file to excel file and retrieve back the data from that file when i install the new app and put it to the newly installed application's DB(sqlite) file.

Comment: I think you can use storage like iCloud or Dropbox for that.. iam not sure